# Use derived type of class template as template template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

Heres an example of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename Tmsg>
class MessageParser{
    public:
        virtual Tmsg Deserialize(const char *buf, size_t len);
};

class JsonParser : MessageParser<int>{
    public:
        int Deserialize(const char *buf, size_t len) override { return 1; };
};

template <class Tmsg>
using rpc_handler_t = void (*)(Tmsg);

template <typename Tmsg, template <typename> class Tparser>
class RpcServer{
    public:
        RpcServer(Tparser<Tmsg> parser) : _parser(parser) {};
        Tparser<Tmsg> _parser;
        void RegisterHandler(rpc_handler_t<Tmsg> handler);
};

int main()
{
    JsonParser parser;
    RpcServer<int, JsonParser> server(parser);

    cout << "Hello World";
}
```

First, it seems that class template parameter deduction is a C++17 feature. I am stuck with C++11. It would be so nice to write `RpcServer(parser)` and have it recognized as a `RpcServer<int, JsonParser>`.

The above gives me:

```
class "JsonParser" is not a class template
```

Fine, it's true. But what does it matter? Why doesn't `JsonParser`, being a `MessageParser<JsonObject>` satisfy the template?

Answer (score 0):

It does not satisfy the template because this syntax is invalid:

```
JsonParser<int> parser;
```

As you can see, it does not compile. It doesn't matter what is its base class and the nature of that base class. `JsonParser` is not a template itself. You can't send template parameter to it.

If it was possible, what would this code do?

```
template<typename T>
struct Base {
    T value = {};
};

// Derived extend `Base<int>`. Therefore Derived has a int value
struct Derived : Base<int> {};

template<template<typename> TT>
void do_stuff() {
    TT<float> g;
    std::cout << g.value;
}

do_stuff<Derived>(); // prints a int or a float?
```

You can only send template classes to template template parameter. You'll have to make `JsonParser` a template:

```
template<typename T>
class JsonParser : MessageParser<T> {
    public:
        T Deserialize(const char *buf, size_t len) override { return 1; };
};
```

Or make your type receive a normal type:

```
template <typename Tparser>
class RpcServer{
    public:
        RpcServer(Tparser parser) : _parser(parser) {};
        Tparser _parser;
};
```

To get back `Tmsg` simply add a typedef, or use `decltype`:

```
template<typename Tmsg>
struct MessageParser {
    using MsgType = Tmsg;

    // ...
};

template <typename Tparser>
class RpcServer{
    using Tmsg = typename Tparser::MsgType;
    
    // or using decltype:
    using Tmsg = decltype(std::declval<Tparser>().Deserialize("", 0));

    public:
        RpcServer(Tparser parser) : _parser(parser) {};
        Tparser _parser;
};
```

I would recommend using a simple type as template parameter.

Comment: The issue with this is that I need to have the `Tmsg` type for another method, `RegisterHandler` (see my edit).

Comment: @MatthewGoulart Is the problem with sending a simple type parameter would be that you don't know how to access the `Tmsg` type?

Comment: Yes, it seems. I was unaware of both of those methods of retrieving `Tmsg` from `Tparser`. I will read into both, thank you!

Comment: I arranged the code as you suggested (with the `using`s) and I got an error: `‘using MsgType = int’ is private within this context`. So I moved the `using` in `JsonParser` under `public:` and now I'm getting: `undefined reference to MessageParser<int>::Deserialize(char const*, unsigned long)`

Comment: @MatthewGoulart that is because you didn't implemented the member function. If you want it to be a pure virtual, you have to put `= 0;` at the end of the declaration